# Cumulative Returns of Multiple Columns from Prices Xts

Tags: r, xts

I have the following data and trying to calculate the compound returns.

```
sample_data <- data.frame(Date = c ("2017-01-31","2017-02-28", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-30"), 
              stock1 = c(9,12,13,14), stock2 = c(5,6,8,9), stock3 = c(4,4.5,5,4), stock4 = c(6,7.8,8,8.5), stock5 = c(5,5.5,6.2,7))
```

Using the xts package I get an error when trying running this code:

```
Return.calculate(sample_data[,c(2:9)], method = c("compound"))
```

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sample_data` is not an `xts` object. It is a `data.frame`. You could do the following to overcome:

```
sample_data <- data.frame(Date = c ("2017-01-31","2017-02-28",
                                    "2017-03-31", "2017-04-30"), 
                          stock1 = c(9,12,13,14), stock2 = c(5,6,8,9),
                          stock3 = c(4,4.5,5,4), stock4 = c(6,7.8,8,8.5),
                          stock5 = c(5,5.5,6.2,7))

class(sample_data)  ## check the structure of your data
x = xts(sample_data[, -1], order.by=as.Date(sample_data$Date))
Return.calculate(x, method = c("compound"))
```

Here is the result:

```
> Return.calculate(x, method = c("compound"))
               stock1    stock2     stock3     stock4     stock5
2017-01-31         NA        NA         NA         NA         NA
2017-02-28 0.28768207 0.1823216  0.1177830 0.26236426 0.09531018
2017-03-31 0.08004271 0.2876821  0.1053605 0.02531781 0.11980120
2017-04-30 0.07410797 0.1177830 -0.2231436 0.06062462 0.12136086
```

Comment: Great thanks you and now if I want to plot a ggplot (geom_line) these stocks on the same graph (ie a line for every stock) is this possible?

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to be doing the right thing, for example stock1 between 2017-01-31 to 2017-02-28 the price went from 9 to 12 which should read 33% and then the subsequent results should compound  on this?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can plot them using `ggplot`. I think its better if you ask a new question.

Comment: It is doing the right think -- when you calculate the compound returns you take the log difference between the prices. In your example it will be `log(12/9)` and this returns `0.287682078`. If you calculate the simple returns your result will be `(12-9)/9` which is `0.33333`. Is this clear?